# Time Difference in PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to create an attendance system. 
[image: Attendance System in PHP]

On check out I call a function which updates attendance in database and calculate hours (Using Codeigniter)

```
public function updateAttendance($data,$id)
    {
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Karachi');
    $attendance=array(
        'check_in'=> $data['check_in'],
        'check_out'=> $data['check_out']
    );
    $this->db->WHERE('id',$id)->update('attendance',$attendance);
    $this->db->query('UPDATE attendance SET hours=(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(check_out,check_in))-1) WHERE DATE(date)=\''.date('Y-m-d').'\' and employee_id='.$id);
    return true;
}
```

I fetch my attendance by employee Id and render a view like this in employee's profile.

[image: Employee Attendance]

The problem is I am getting wrong calculation of hours, probably due to my query. Is there a fix by query or do I have to do keep time diff in time format and then add all of them at the end of month and then get hours out of it.

Comment: The "-1" in the query (HOUR(TIMEDIFF(check_out,check_in))-1) is a requirement because company subtracts the lunch hour from total hours.

Comment: Have you tried calculating the time difference while displaying the result, not by fetching table data for stored `hour` column in mysql table?

Comment: oh no, but i was thinking to do that too. the thing is I have hours as a column in attendance table to store hours on daily basis. But the INT nature of HOUR function gives me only floor value which wastes a lot of minutes for every employee on daily basis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this one...

```
$to_time = strtotime("2008-12-13 10:42:00");
$from_time = strtotime("2008-12-13 10:21:00");
echo round(abs($to_time - $from_time) / 60,2). " minute";
```

Comment: replace devide by 60  to (60*60) and minutes to hours

Comment: make sense.. lemme try that. , Thanks @Pravin

Comment: I tried it see the results here http://prntscr.com/dswi9x @ Pravin. I guess i have to remove round function and keep the value in decimal format.

Comment: Depending what the needs of the company/client are, you could use something like `round(2* ($end-$start)/(3600))/2` which would round the hours to the nearest half hour (replace with 4's to round to nearest 15 minute mark of 0, 15, 30, 45).

Answer (score 1):

i think its better to use this function:

```
$ MY_TIME = strtotime('2017-01-04 23:12');
```

this line of code return this digits: 1483571520

you can doing operation on them

and you can return them to date format for saving in database with this function:

```
date('y-m-d H:i',$MY_TIME);
```

Comment: nima bro. I am very well aware of unix timestamp and strtotime() function. Are you trying to say that I should keep seconds in database and than subtract them to get my required hours? that will still give me wrong answer. Anyone else has better solution

Comment: Why would that give you the wrong answer? `($end-$start)/(60*60)` should do it

Comment: I don't think the seconds are necessary

Comment: @jhecht,  ($end-$start)/(60*60) works perfectly , I was referring to the round() function.

Comment: prntscr.com/dswi9x this is what I am getting now

Comment: Why not simply use `floor()`, `ceil()`, or `round()` (depending what would work best).

Answer (score 1):

```
$time = new DateTime($givenTime);
$time->diff(new DateTime());
```

Try this code it may help you better.

Answer (score 0):

Okay here is a very native php function that might help you. I have been in the same problem and I solved it with this. You don't need a date on this one, only the time.

```
function timeDiff($time_start = null, $time_end = null, $hour_mode = true)
  {
    $to_time = strtotime($time_start);
    $from_time = strtotime($time_end);
    $hour = 0;

    if ($hour_mode) { // Outputs in hours i.e. 8.50, 10.32
      $hour = round(abs($to_time - $from_time) / 60 / 60, 1); 
    }
    else {
      $hour = round(abs($to_time - $from_time) / 60, 1); // Outputs in minutes i.e. 3360, 500
    }    

    if ($time_end < $time_start) {
        if ($hour_mode) {   
            $hour -= 24; // outputs in hours         
        }
        else {
            $hour -= 1440; // outputs in minutes
        }
    }

    return abs($hour);
  }
```

**Usage**

```
echo timeDiff('01:00:00', '02:00:00'); // Outputs '1' in hourly format
echo timeDiff('01:00:00', '02:00:00', false); // Outputs '60' in minute format
```

Just copy and paste the function anywhere you want in your php sourcecode and that's it! Hope this helps!